# How to automatically back up a local Git repo to the same machine?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I know there are posts already asking about it, but they mostly refer to doing manual backups, not automatic.

I'm going to use Git for Unity game development so I have to use LFS. I'm working solo so I want to keep everything local.

I want to set it up like this: working directory on my SSD and LFS cache on my bigger HDD. I also want to back up my repo to the HDD (without the LFS cache, it's already there), but I'm not sure what's the proper way of doing that. I though about setting up a remote on my HDD and then pushing to it from my repo on SSD. This seems like the best way to keep a backup of my repo on the other drive to me, but I'm not sure if it's possible. I didn't find many articles detailing how to set this up so I'm concerned that I'm missing some better solution. Is this even possible, if no what's the "proper" way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A remote can be local or remote; this makes no difference to git.  You just have to specify an appropriate URL for the remote (or for any reference to a repo).

I often use file://localhost/path/to/repo

On a windows machine, that might look like file://localhost/c/repos/myRepo or something of the sort.

If that doesn't clarify how you would set it up, then you may need to be more specific about what question you have; this should work just the same as setting up any other remote.

LFS needn't be an issue here; since you're just wanting to back up the core repo's database, the remote doesn't even need an LFS configuration.

As for automation, I suppose you could use hooks.  For example, a post-commit hook could push all refs to the remote, so that all new commits get replicated automatically.  (A hook is just a script placed in the .git/hooks directory, which git will execute when certain events occur.)  You can look up the git documentation on hooks for information about what all of the possible events are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this looks great. I have one problem: when I try to push commited changes I get an error `local push doesn't(yet) support pushing to non-bare repositories`. I'm using GitKraken, should I switch the GUI or is there something wrong with the way I've set it up?

Comment: @WojtekWencel : I'm not familiar with GitKraken so can't speak to any issues it might introduce; I just use the git command-line tools (in git bash on Windows).  What version of git are you using?  I'm unable to reproduce that symptom.  (That said, it may be that the simplest solution would be to use a bare repo for the backup.)

Comment: Bare repo seems like the best choice form me when I think about it. One more question before I set this up: does it contain everything I need in case my drive with working directory dies? Will I be able to recover my project just from this bare repo?

Answer (score 1):

> I though about setting up a remote on my HDD and then pushing to it from my repo on SSD.

This seems you are going to [set up a Git server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server), which can be used as a "remote backup" of your repository.

Also, you may know that [a remote repo can be at your computer local](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

And, you may consider some other backup method like [rsync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rsync#As_a_backup_utility) besides using a Git remote repository.